# "Compile Error" while Creating a Function with Multiple ParamArray

Tags: excel, vba

I want to include a ParamArray in my function, but my efforts have failed so far.

Let's say I want to build a function to calculate mean for discrete distribution.

The function has the following form:

```
Function Dist_Discrete(X1, P1, X2, P2, X3, P3, etc.)
```

There are two solutions currently come to my mind:

1. Using optional arguments multiple of times.
2. Using ParamArray

The second one is preferred. But here is some problem when I try to define

```
Function Dist_Discrete(ParamArray XVal() As Variant, ParamArray Prob() As Variant)
```

And an error message comes up - "Compile error"

I can find a way to go around this by setting even as probability and odd as value. But I think this might be a good temporary solution

Comment: `ParamArray` can only be used for the last parameter of a parameter list, which implies you can only have one.

Comment: if more than one `ParamArray` were somehow allowed, there would be no way to guess where the first one ends and the second one starts

Answer (score 4):

Your posted example shows the inputs as cells in a contiguous column like **X1**, **X2**. etc.  If this is the case, the just use `Range` objects as the inputs:

```
Function Dist_Discrete(X as Range, P as Range) as Double
```

then in a worksheet cell:

```
=DistDiscrete(X1:X30, P1:P30)
```

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right. I was overthinking and complicating the problem

Answer (score 4):

> ParamArray specifies that a procedure parameter takes an optional array of elements of the specified type. ParamArray can be used only on the last parameter of a parameter list. Thus 2 param arrays are not possible. ([learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/paramarray))

However, you may think about a little trick in Excel. E.g. lets consider the following Function:

`Function SumAndMultiply(valuesToSum(), valuesToMultiply()) as Double`
which has the idea to sum the values of the `valuesToSum()` array and to multiply the result with each of the `valuesToMultiply()`.

In VBA, if the first one is presented as a range, then it would work quite nicely:

[image]

```
Public Function SumAndMultiply(valuesToSum As Range, _
        ParamArray valuesToMultiply() As Variant) As Double

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim sum As Double
    For Each myCell In valuesToSum
        sum = sum + myCell
    Next myCell

    Dim param As Variant
    SumAndMultiply = sum
    For Each param In valuesToMultiply
        SumAndMultiply = SumAndMultiply * param
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: thank you so much. That's right. I was overthinking and complicating the problem :(